# How to search in specific website but not its sub sections?

Tags: google-search

For example:

I want to search for *web hosting* in domain *css-tricks.com*. So I will do this:

```
site:css-tricks.com web hosting
```

But that site has a forum section at http://css-tricks.com/forums/. I don't want any result from the forums discussions.

Is there any regular expression or trick to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude things in the URL by using `-inurl:` like so:

```
site:css-tricks.com web hosting -inurl:/forums
```

There is a fairly comprehensive list of the various operators on [this page](http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators.html).